# What percentage of users use a cookie blocker?

Tags: cookie

I would like to know whether there is a way to get numbers on those users enabling cookie blocker. As far as I know Google Analytics is tracking you by creating cookies. Is there a way to assess the quantity of those using cookie blocker or exploit other questions related to this topic?

Comment: "cookie blocker" - you mean real users who have _disabled_ cookies?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know how generally assess the quantity of those who have disabled the cookies...or how to use metrics or any kind of approaches to tackle this issue

Comment: Whenever I hear a question like this, I know that the question is on the perimeter of the real problem- that there is a more direct question that has not been asked. Cookies are "actively" blocked only by only a few users on the scale of users. They are your more technically savvy users. However, some page requests cannot process cookies such as bots. I assume that you have an issue that you want to explore regarding people and cookies. Keep in mind that most browsers can block cookies so "blockers" are less necessary. But these features are seldom set by ordinary folks.

Comment: I use [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vanilla-cookie-manager/gieohaicffldbmiilohhggbidhephnjj?hl=en) which doesn't _block_ cookies, but converts all cookies to session cookies unless I've whitelisted the site. As soon as I close the tab, the cookies go away. And my whitelist is fairly short.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on your site you would use a scripting language e.g. PHP, and attempt to save a cookie.  If it doesn't save, +1

Here is a solution using PHP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859333/how-would-i-test-if-a-cookie-is-set-using-php-and-if-its-not-set-do-nothing

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask you to expand your answer a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do the coding for you.  If that much information doesn't help, then you are going to keep coming back looking for answers.  You now know the principle, you need to learn how to do it. 

It sounds like you don't know any PHP, learning even the basics is worth doing.

Comment: No no, its not about coding. Do you mind to expand the answer regarding your idea.

Comment: I have added a link.  You would attempt to set the cookie, then test whether or not it is set.  If it isn't you would update a counter somewhere, likely in a mySQL database, but that is up to you.  You can get an email each time you like :P

Comment: The link isn't really a "solution" to this particular problem. An important point is that you can only check for the existence of the cookie on the second request. Also, unless you intelligently check for bots and discount them you're not going to be counting real users... most non-cookie-supporting traffic is going to be from bots.